# How to check if phone is on idle or if phone gets out of the idle state?

Tags: android, state

I have a class that extends the BroadcastReciever and another that extends the AsyncTask

I wanted it so that when it receives an sms it would fire up a timer using the 'AsyncTask-extended' class.
After, lets just say, 30 seconds, **given that the phone has been idle or didn't receive any user input for the whole 30 seconds**, it would run a function.
Otherwise, it would stop the timer.

I already got the timer part down (Although, randomly it would stop prematurely)
And now I'm stuck at figuring out how to check if there was any user input given while the timer is running.

Could someone show me how to check for said user input?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So basically what you need to listen to the ACTION_SCREEN_ON broadcast intent.

The steps to implement it:

> 1) Set up BroadcastReceiver for SMS. Let's call it SMSBroadcastReceiver.
>
> 2) On your SMSBroadcastReceiver.onReceive method you will have to do two things:
>
> 2.1) Use [AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html) to schedule a future execution of your function. No need to use AsyncTasks.
>
> 2.2) Register a new BroadcastReceiver that listens for the [ACTION_SCREEN_ON](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_SCREEN_ON) event. The implementation of this receiver should cancel the operation scheduled on step 2.1.

Also, consider registering the SMSBroadcastReceiver only on [ACTION_SCREEN_OFF](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_SCREEN_OFF)

Comment: Whenever I unlock my phone, it receives the [USER_PRESENT](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_USER_PRESENT) instead of ACTION_SCREEN_ON .(Could this be because I have a lock screen enabled?)  
So I'm using both, just in-case. Other than that everything's good  
Thanks!

Comment: Apparently, to receive the ACTION_SCREEN_ON and ACTION_SCREEN_OFF you need to set the receivers programatically. I'm guessing this is done so the system doesn't takes for ever to wake up/go to sleep if there are too many apps hooked up to this events. Glad it worked !

Comment: I see, i had mine set-up on the .xml file. So that's why, good to know!

Answer (score 0):

When phone goes idle the method onStop() of your current activity will be called. Override this method and do what you wanna when it is called. When the phone gets back from idle state the methods OnResume() and onRestart() will be called, you can also override them. Se more about activity lifecycle here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html

Comment: This would've been fine if I was working on a class that extended the Activity class. The [onUserInteraction()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onUserInteraction%28%29) method would've been a simple solution